# Implement auto saving with local storage on a custom text field with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm trying to implement an auto saving function with React and everything is working fine when i'm saving to local storage but my problem is when i for example close the window and try to retrieve the data i don't want to get them from the local storage but instead from the editorData function. I'm not really sure how to approach this problem.

```
const Editor = ({ data, setFieldValue, fieldProps, t }) => {
    const editorName = fieldProps.name;
    const [editorData, setEditorData] = useState(
        element.setData(editorName, data)
    );
    const storageData = localStorage.getItem(`editorData`);
    useEffect(() => {
        setFieldValue(
            editorName,
            element.convertDataToFieldType(editorName, editorData)
        );
        setInterval(function() {
            localStorage.setItem(`editorData`, JSON.stringify(editorData));
        }, 20000);
    }, [editorData]);

    return (
        <Pages
            editorData={JSON.parse(storageData) || editorData}
            setEditorData={setEditorData}
            editorName={editorName}
            setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
        />
    );
};
```

On the Pages component inside the return i'm taking the local storage data and if not the editor data.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do. Where is the onChange function?

Comment: I mean from the editorData, basically when i mount the component i want to use the local storage at first to retrieve the data from the editor but then i want to use editorData

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, that I understood your problem correctly, but i suggest, that you can use sessionStorage instead of localStorage.
It also allows you to store data in browser, but if you close tab or browser this data will be removed.
So you can use it, and every time you want to access your data you can simply check is there any data in your sessionStorage, if it is - just grab it, if no - use your function.
So If user will close the window, next time he'll open it - sessionStorage will be empty